# Difference in value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple audit table:

```
PersonID   Date    Value

01        1/1/17   Faulkner
01        1/2/17   Hemingway
```

Which shows me where a person's surname has changed and the date this happened.

Please can someone advise if there is a report I can run / which T-SQL I should use that will just bring up when a person's surname has changed, e.g. just display row 2 above?

Suggestions /ideas very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [PersonId] INT
   ,[Date] DATE
   ,[value] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([PersonId], [Date], [value])
VALUES (1, '1/1/17', 'Faulkner')
      ,(1, '1/2/17', 'Hemingway')
      ,(2, '1/1/17', 'Faulkner')
      ,(3, '1/2/17', 'Faulkner 1')
      ,(3, '1/3/17', 'Faulkner 2')
      ,(3, '1/3/17', 'Faulkner 3');

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  PersonId
           ,Date 
           ,Value
           ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId) as cnt
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY [Date] DESC) as [rowID]
    FROM @DataSource
)

SELECT PersonId, Date, Value
FROM CTE
WHERE cnt > 1
    AND [rowID] = 1
ORDER BY Date;
```

It will give you only records which have been updated but returning the lats value only.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see the OP only wants the last row. In this case, your answer is better than mine.